# SQL reverse column value query

Tags: sql, t-sql

Need some Sql help? My Sql is not quite up to this yet.
I have a table

```
ColA    ColB    ColC
A       B       101
B       B       102
C       B       102
B       A       108
```

I need to be able identify the values in ColC where the rows that have the same entry in  Col A and Col B (but reversed) i.e  where Col B = Col A.  But not like row three where Col B corresponding value  has no match or row two where Col A = Col B.

The results set would be

```
Col A      Col B     Col C
A          B         101
B          A         108
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do a self join - ie: join the table to itself...

```
select t1.* , t1.ColC-t2.ColC
from yourtable t1
    inner join yourtable t2
       on t1.colA = t2.colB
       and t1.colB = t2.colA
where t1.colA <> t1.colB
```

Comment: Thanks Podiluska, Now I am going to work on how to get the values that are produced and subtract the one from the another, where there is a matched opposite pair.

Comment: @icecurtain I've added the difference in. You may want an `ABS` around it.